# How to get the date on a datepicker?

Tags: javascript, grails, groovy, datepicker

I am really new to javascript and jquery. I wanted to get the value of the date selected by the user via datepicker, and use the value in my javascript. The name of my datepicker is birthDate. This is my html code for the date picker:

```
       <guis:datePicker required="true" label="Birthdate"
           bean="${accountInfo}" field="birthDate"
           value="${accountInfo?.birthDate?:"none"}"
           noSelection="${['null':'']}"/>
```

My javascript is:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">                      
                function isOfLegalAge() {    
                  var currDate = new Date();
                  var birthDate = $("#datepicker").val();  
                  var diff = currDate - birthDate
                  alert (currDate);
                  alert(birthDate);                      
                      if(diff >= 18){
                          return true;                              
                      }else {                         
                          alert("You must be atleast 18 years old to register!");
                          document.location.href = '/user';
                          return false;                          
                      }
                      return true;
                }
           </script>
```

The value returned by the datepicker is in this format:

Wed Jun 13 00:00:00 PHT 1990

..while the new Date is:

Wed Jun 06 2012 17:08:52 GMT+0800 (PHT)

Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As you have said that you got the date in `dd/mm/yyyy` formatTry this,

```
var myDate = "06/06/2012";
var currentDate = new Date();
var compareDate = currentDate.getDate() + "/" + currentDate.getMonth() + "/" + currentDate.getFullYear();
if (myDate == compareDate)
    alert("Both dates are equal!");
else
    alert("Dates mismatch!");
```

In case, if you are using jQuery also, you can do this:

```
var date = '06/06/2012';
var arrDate = date.split("/");
var today = new Date();
useDate = new Date(arrDate[2], arrDate[1] -1, arrDate[0]);

if (useDate == today)
    alert("Both dates are equal!");
else
    alert("Dates mismatch!");
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: using == is evil use === also comparing date with `equals` is error prone :O

Comment: thanks for your answer. What I am trying to compare is the current date with the date specified by the user using the datepicker..based on your example, you have specified the date to be compared on the current date..

Comment: @chemilleX3 Okay, in that case, you can use `var date = $('#datepicker').val();` Just this change is enough.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar: actually, I am trying that code now, but everytime I call the alert method, what is being displayed is "undefined", that means the date from the datepicker is not retrieved using the var date = $('#datepicker').val(); code in javascript...is there any other way?Please help..

Comment: @chemilleX3, Can you please post the full code? The HTML Markup of the DatePicker?

Comment: @chemilleX3 Can you post the HTML rendered?

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="birthDate" value="date.struct">
<select name="birthDate_month" id="birthDate_month"><option value="null"></option>
<select name="birthDate_day" id="birthDate_day"><option value="null"></option>
<select name="birthDate_year" id="birthDate_year"><option value="null"></option>

Comment: @chemilleX3 Change the code to `var date = $('[name="birthDate"]').val();` as you haven't given any ID.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar: nothing is returned when I used var date = $('[name="birthDate"]').val(); but the month is returned when I used this code: var date = $('[name="birthDate_month"]').val(); with numeric format, like if I input January, "1" is returned when I executed my code. Is there a way for me to bind the month, day, and year returned?

Comment: yeah, you can do. use this `var d = new Date($('[name="birthDate_day"]').val() + '/' + $('[name="birthDate_month"]').val() + '/' + $('[name="birthDate_year"]').val());`

Answer (score 2):

if you have it in `#datepicker` id element you can use val to get value and turn it into Date like this:

```
new Date( $('#datepicker').val() )
```

this will give you back `Wed Jun 20 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)` :)

Cheers!

Comment: Im trying this code in my javascript: 
   var currDate = new Date();
   var birthDate = $("#datepicker").val();
   alert (currDate);
   alert(birthDate);

What is being displayed is only the current date which is in the format Wed Jun 06 2012 16:43:07 GMT+0800 (PHT), but the date entered by the user is not captured by the above command..please help :(

Comment: try more with `console.log(variable)` rather then alert and open firefox / chrome / safari developer console. It shows much more.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<form:input cssStyle="background-image:url('../images/DateCal.png'); 
                               background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position: right;" 
                               path="requirementDate" id="datepicker1" 
                               />

  $(document).ready(function() {
      var dates= $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '2012:2022'

        });

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
```